# SQL error when I try to run my project (error 50)?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to build a project data base SQL in my web application project (visual studio) I tried to off the firewall and I got this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Comment: Well what does the Windows Application event log say?

Comment: Are you using `LocalDB` or an installed `Sql Server`? The first wont work from another location then where the LocalDB is installed

Comment: Probably LocalDB, it came with the installation of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, then do the following:

- Search for "Services" in Cortona
- Open the "Services" app
- Scroll down to "SQL Server(MSSQLSEERVER)"
- Now go to its properties and start the service

Also, make sure you are using the correct connection string.